# How do I cache my custom entities using entity api with entitycache?

Tags: 7, entities

I have implemented custom entites, extending on Entity API. This is essentially identical to what the [Model module](http://drupal.org/project/model) does with a few extra customisations (fields, solr/facet integration etc).

I want to cache my custom entities using the [Entity Cache](http://drupal.org/project/entitycache) module to get fast loading of entities when using Views and Apachesolr along with automatic cache updating when my entities are updated.

What do I have to do to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this quite easily with a few hooks and additions to your existing hooks.

Define the cache table in your hook_schema() implementation in your module's .install file:

```
// Optional cache table for entitycache support.
$schema['cache_entity_my_entity'] = drupal_get_schema_unprocessed('system', 'cache');
$schema['cache_entity_my_entity']['description'] = 'Cache table used to store my_entity entity records.';
```

This adds a db table that can be used to store your cached entities.

Add an update hook to create the table:

```
function my_entity_update_700X() {
  if (!db_table_exists('cache_entity_my_entity')) {
    $schema = drupal_get_schema_unprocessed('system', 'cache');
    $schema['description'] = 'Cache table used to store my_entity entity records.';
    db_create_table('cache_entity_my_entity', $schema);
  }
}
```

Enable entitycache in hook_entity_info(). Add this near the bottom before return $info;

```
if (module_exists('entitycache')) {
  $info['my_entity']['field cache'] = FALSE;
  $info['my_entity']['entity cache'] = TRUE;
}
```

Implement hook_flush_caches() in your .module file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_flush_caches().
 */
function my_entity_flush_caches() {
  return array('cache_entity_my_entity');
}
```

And that's it! Entity API takes care of the interactions and things like load() and resetCache() (I found you have to implement those functions when adding entitycache functionality to non-entityapi entities)